# Fish fertilizer for my lawn

Tags: lawn, fertilizer

I was told by someone that fish fertilizer is good for the lawn; just use 3 tablespoons in a gallon of water and apply it to the lawn.  But how many gallons should I use for a lawn that's about .3 acre?  There really wasn't any instructions for that, other than to apply it every 6 weeks.

Comment: Any slow release fertilizer, organic or manufactured, is helpful for a lawn but you may find yourself making friends with animals who like the smell.  Try a test patch to see how it works out.

Comment: Definitely apply the bare minimum and beware of downwind neighbors who are extra sensitive.

Comment: I'd like to know what happens if you use fish fertilizer on open ground, lawned or otherwise - in my experience, not only is it not pleasant to smell, but every foraging animal in a radius of 5 miles will be along to visit to find the source of this delectable (as far as they're concerned) scent...

Answer (score 4):

Application is 1/2" gallon per 1000 sq ft.

0.3 acre is 13,000 square feet

For 6 1/2" gallons of solution.

Add a teaspoon or two of molasses, it's reported to cut the smell if you're having difficulties with that.

Answer (score 4):

In [this answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/697/51) I went through the math on figuring out how far fish fertilizer goes. I'll assume here for the sake of reusing that math that your fish fertilizer is 3% nitrogen (e.g. 3-3-1 or some similar analysis).

Your 0.3 acre is 13,000 square feet. If your lawn needs 2 pounds of Nitrogen per 1000 square feet (a soil test will tell you the right amount), then you need 26 pounds of nitrogen. If each gallon of diluted fertilizer has 0.001 pounds... you need a **lot** of fertilizer! It would take 1000 gallons of diluted fertilizer to provide 1 pound of nitrogen, or 26,000 gallons to fertilize your whole lawn.

1 gallon of straight fertilizer would make up about 250 gallons of dilution, so you'd need 104 gallons to produce the 26k gallons to fertilize your entire lawn.

If you have higher nitrogen content in your fertilizer, then you will need less. (E.g. if you have 6% nitrogen, you can cut the amounts in half.)

An organic solid fertilizer that is formulated for lawns will probably be cheaper and easier to apply...

Answer (score 2):

Fish fertilizer is not intended to meet the N-P-K needs but rather to serve as a foliar amendment to provide amino acids and other organic components that conventional fertilizer does not provide.  The oil in the fish fertilizer is also beneficial to both the plants and microbial organisms in the soil.

Three ounces per 1,000 square feet is virtually the same as one gallon per acre.  Regarding the smell, fish emulsions are usually the culprit.  Try fish hydrolysate and you will likely notice a vast improvement in the smell of the product after application.